# Is there an alias or name parameter for dataclass arguments?

Tags: python, keyword-argument, python-dataclasses

I have a class that accepts a lot of params, and in init method I'm loading them in differently named params. I know it might be a bad design or whatever, but I can't change that right now. I've tried a lot of stuff but nothing really did the thing. Is it possible to do it within dataclasses?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, vp):
        self.viewport = vp
```

I know that this is not intended behaviour of dataclass but I'm wondering if it's possible to make some workaround.

What I'd like to have is this mapping within dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class MyClass:
   viewport:str = "" # this should get the value from vp argument if possible

so when I call:
mc = MyClass(vp="foo")
print(mc) should return (MyClass(viewport="foo"))
```

Comment: is not clear what you mean, can you complete your example? maybe put something that is not working and you want to make it work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PabloRuiz I've added additional context, hope that this clarifies it

Comment: Working around bad design, claiming the bad design cannot be changed, while still having very specific yet seemingly arbitrary design requirements (like "must be a dataclass") smells a lot like an XY Problem. A clean separation like user @user2246849 suggests is likely the best solution if there somehow is a good reason to do all this - but I suspect there's probably an underlying problem you're not mentioning, or the situation isn't as inflexible as you're making it out to be.

Comment: @Grismar the problem I'm having is that this is the part of the already existing system, and I've just started updating part by part, can't really change the whole thing and I wanted to start with simple changes in the beginning so this is just a starting phase of a structural refactor of an bigger project. Basically a hack until it's possible to have it the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [`InitVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables) for the `vp` alias.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar


@dataclass
class MyClass:
    viewport: str = ""  # this should get the value from vp argument if possible
    vp: InitVar[str] = None

    def __post_init__(self, vp):
        if vp:
            self.viewport = vp


mc = MyClass(vp="foo")
```

If you need to define many aliases, you could also write your own decorator that uses [`Field.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.Field) like so:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields
from functools import wraps


def _wrap_init(original_init):
    @wraps(original_init)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        aliases = {}
        for field in fields(self):
            alias = field.metadata.get("alias")
            if alias is not None:
                value = kwargs.pop(alias)
                aliases[field.name] = value

        original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

        for name, value in aliases.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)

    return __init__


def aliased(cls):
    original_init = cls.__init__
    cls.__init__ = _wrap_init(original_init)
    return cls


@aliased
@dataclass
class MyClass:
    viewport: str = field(default="", metadata={"alias": "vp"})


mc = MyClass(vp="foo")
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I have a lot of arguments like this, so if I do for every arg like this it'll just be a mess. @pypae like 10+ params are like that.

Comment: I don't think that there is an easier way. Of course you could write your own decorator to reduce the boilerplate. I updated my answer to include an example.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


arg_dict = {'vp':'viewport'}

@dataclass
class RealMyClass():
    viewport: str = ''
    some_other_field: int = 10
        
        
class MyClass(RealMyClass):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**{arg_dict[arg]:value for arg, value in kwargs.items()})


print(MyClass(vp='foo'))
```

```
MyClass(viewport='foo', some_other_field=10)
```

Comment: @rv.kvetch Thanks, you are correct, I edited with the imports, (which is just `datacass`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any context where this would be a good idea, but you can do it in this way:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, InitVar
@dataclass
class MyClass:
    vp: InitVar[str]
    viewport: str = field(init=False)
    def __post_init__(self,vp):
        self.viewport = vp
        
MyClass(vp='hola')
```

Which will return:

```
MyClass(viewport='hola')
```