# How to alias class attributes when creating NamedTuple?

Tags: python, alias, namedtuple

I want to alias `project_version` with `init_version`, but since NamedTuple is a factory method I'm having difficulty in doing this.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class ProjectMetadata(NamedTuple):
    """Structure holding project metadata derived from `pyproject.toml`"""

    config_file: Path
    package_name: str
    project_name: str
    project_path: Path
    project_version: str
    source_dir: Path
```

I've tried the basic alias technique but met with undefined `init_version` errors.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class ProjectMetadata(NamedTuple):
    """Structure holding project metadata derived from `pyproject.toml`"""

    config_file: Path
    package_name: str
    project_name: str
    project_path: Path
    project_version: str = init_version
    source_dir: Path
```

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351032/named-tuple-and-default-values-for-optional-keyword-arguments) help at all?

Comment: Have you considered using a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) instead? Then set `frozen=True` to prevent assignment. See [Is there an alias or name parameter for dataclass arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72170886/2745495)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "alias"? Do you want that you can access `metadata.init_version` and get `metadata.project_version`?

Comment: And if so, why do you think that's preferable to having a single name for this particular attribute of your data structure?

Comment: This is part of a much larger codebase, essentially I want to deprecate `project_version` by renaming it with `init_version` but still want it to be backwards compatible. I can't change it directly as this would be a breaking change and not backwards compatible. I want to treat `project_version` and `init_version` as being the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) named `init_version` to the class which returns the `project_version` attribute:

```
class ProjectMetadata(NamedTuple):
    # ...
    project_version: str

    @property
    def init_version(self) -> str:
        return self.project_version
```